# conversion from string to type 'Integer' is not valid in below code

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub CreatFolder()  
    ' the line below gives error like Conversion from string "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Createfolders" to type 'Integer' is not valid
    Dim directoryPath As String = Path.GetInvalidpathChars(Server.MapPath("..\Cre_Folders\File\") & txtFolderName.Text.Trim())

    If Not Directory.Exists(directoryPath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath)
        lblsuccess.Visible = True
        'lblmsg.Visible = False
        lblValidName.Visible = False
        lblDelete.Visible = False
        lblerr.Visible = False
    Else
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "alert", "alert('Folder already existed.');", True)
        'lblmsg.Text = "Directory Already Exists..."
        lblValidName.Visible = False
        lblDelete.Visible = False
        lblsuccess.Visible = False
        lblerr.Visible = False
    End If

    Call Treeview()
End Sub
```

Comment: Separate Sever.MapPath into a variable of its own and from there set a break point and examine its content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i accept illegal characters in the path for the below code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699335/how-can-i-accept-illegal-characters-in-the-path-for-the-below-code)

Comment: Presenting a piece of code without specifying problem and asking a question? -1

Comment: @igrimpe, somewhere in Reddit there gotta be a link: [***`Free debugging service`***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: You have two questions on SO, which are completely identical now (after editing) - do you expect more answers, because of that? You'll get more answers if you IMPROVE your question: What do you want to do, what code did you try, what is the result or exlicit error - including line.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are getting is a compile-time error not a run-time error.

The method Path.GetInvalidPathChars() does not validate a path. It does not take a string and tell you if is good or bad.  Instead it returns an array of chars that are known to be invalid in the OS being used. [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

Also note that the returned list of chars may not be complete - See: [Missing ? & *](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/01/11/351060.aspx).

Comment: Correct about `GetInvalidPathChars`, but I think this is a runtime error: because this is VB and (I'm guessing) `Option Strict` is off, it's trying to convert the result of `Server.MapPath` to an `Integer` array index, hence the exception.